# MYSQL: How to count duplicated rows and attach markers to the existing values

Tags: mysql, sql

Issue: The MIDL column is supposed to include (UL_ID, "x001"), x001 representing a unique household. If there are duplicated households, then the base of the MIDL should stay the same, while the second value increases by 1 (which means there is more than one household on the said address). Now, I managed to cheat with numbers up to 9 for a while, because I can set the base as (UL_ID, "x00") and simply add values for each additional duplicate, but once you go over 9, you end up with x0010, while the value can't exceed 12 characters. NOTE: The number of households extends to 60 in some cases.

Before:

```
ADDRESS                    MIDL              UL_ID
---------------------------------------------------
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 6                          14044272
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 6                          14044272
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 6                          14044272
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 6A                         14044264
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 7                          14044299
BAZOVIŠKA ULICA 25                         14037390
BELOKRIŠKA CESTA 10                        17097687
BELOKRIŠKA CESTA 10                        17097687
BELOKRIŠKA CESTA 10                        17097687
BELOKRIŠKA CESTA 10                        17097687
```

After:

```
ADDRESS                    MIDL              UL_ID
----------------------------------------------------
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 6       14044272x001        14044272
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 6       14044272x002        14044272
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 6       14044272x003        14044272
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 6A      14044264x001        14044264
AŠKERČEVA ULICA 7       14044299x001        14044299
BAZOVIŠKA ULICA 25      14037390x001        14037390
BELOKRIŠKA CESTA 10     17097687x001        17097687
BELOKRIŠKA CESTA 10     17097687x002        17097687
BELOKRIŠKA CESTA 10     17097687x003        17097687
BELOKRIŠKA CESTA 10     17097687x004        17097687
```

**UPDATE**

P.Salmon thought up of a working solution

```
SELECT T.ADDRESS,
     CONCAT(T.UL_ID,'x' ,lpad(IF(T.UL_ID <> @P,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1),3,'0')) MIDL, T.UL_ID,
     @P:=T.UL_ID P
FROM (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0) RN,T
```

Comment: Of relevance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "managed to cheat with numbers up to 9 for a while, because I can set the base as (UL_ID, "x00") and simply add values for each additional duplicate" using a cursor you could instead use a rownumber as suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen
something like this

```
 SELECT T.ADDRESS,
         CONCAT(T.UL_ID,'x' ,lpad(IF(T.UL_ID <> @P,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1),3,'0')) midl,
         T.UL_ID,
         @P:=T.UL_ID P
FROM    (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0) RN,T
ORDER   BY  T.UL_ID
```

If you already using this method you may just need the concat..lpad bits.

Same thing using address

```
SELECT T.ADDRESS,
         CONCAT(T.UL_ID,'x' ,lpad(IF(T.address <> @P,@RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1),3,'0')) midl,
         T.UL_ID,
         @P:=T.address P
FROM    (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:='') RN,T
ORDER   BY  T.address
```

Result

```
+----------+--------------+----------+----------+
| ADDRESS  | midl         | UL_ID    | P        |
+----------+--------------+----------+----------+
| CESTA 10 | 17097687x001 | 17097687 | CESTA 10 |
| CESTA 10 | 17097687x002 | 17097687 | CESTA 10 |
| CESTA 10 | 17097687x003 | 17097687 | CESTA 10 |
| CESTA 10 | 17097687x004 | 17097687 | CESTA 10 |
| ULICA 25 | 14037390x001 | 14037390 | ULICA 25 |
| ULICA 6  | 14044272x001 | 14044272 | ULICA 6  |
| ULICA 6  | 14044272x002 | 14044272 | ULICA 6  |
| ULICA 6  | 14044272x003 | 14044272 | ULICA 6  |
| ULICA 6A | 14044264x001 | 14044264 | ULICA 6A |
| ULICA 7  | 14044299x001 | 14044299 | ULICA 7  |
+----------+--------------+----------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this will only work if the table is ordered by UL_ID

Comment: Could you take a minute of your time and explain to me, why this method doesn't work if I decide to count the ADDRESS while still using the UL_ID as reference. In my understanding it should essentially work the same, except it doesn't. Instead it counts up until 999 (it's limited by 3, I get this part) and resets. I fail to see why it wouldn't work, as it is only supposed to compare the duplicates. Does it has anything to do with characters, as the UL_ID is composed strictly out of numbers?

Comment: Adephx - not sure I understand your comment. if you you post your code on sql fiddle I'll take a look at it. Note - if you run 2 bits of code in the same script which use the same @ variables you will get an issue where the second query just keeps incrementing the row number - I don't know why this is but you could try SETting the variables between the queries or use different variable names in the second query.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. In your code, I can replace UL_ID with any other parameter in my table (I have several others that I haven't listed here) and the code will work perfectly (it will count the number of duplicates in that column, attach either UL_ID or something else as prefix then add the count as x00~), but if I select ADDRESS as the column that is supposed to be counted the code breaks. TLDR: I wanted to replace UL_ID with ADDRESS

Comment: Adephx I have added query based on address - looks ok to me

Comment: Yeah, looks ok to me as well, weird. I tried exactly the same method yesterday and it gave the wrong result. Cheers, thank you for taking your time, I wish I could upvote your reply, but my rep is under 15.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the count, you will need a subquery. Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    t.ADDRESS,
    CONCAT(t.UL_ID, "x", LPAD(count.UL_ID_COUNT, 3, '0')) AS MIDL,
    t.UL_ID
FROM <your table> AS t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UL_ID, COUNT(UL_ID) AS UL_ID_COUNT FROM <your table> GROUP BY UL_ID
) AS count ON count.UL_ID = t.UL_ID;
```

I am also using [`LPAD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) and [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to create `MIDL`.

You can also create a MySQL `UPDATE` using the same idea:

```
UPDATE <your table> AS t
SET MIDL=CONCAT(t.UL_ID, "x", LPAD(count.UL_ID_COUNT, 3, '0'))
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT UL_ID, COUNT(UL_ID) AS UL_ID_COUNT FROM <your table> GROUP BY UL_ID
) AS count ON count.UL_ID = t.UL_ID;
```

Comment: I had to remove _COUNT from count.UL_ID_COUNT to make it work, but then all the values return as UL_IDx162. The solution from P.Salmon seems to work.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to name the columns in the subquery :) It should work now.

Comment: I've checked your solution again, and while it works for counting the total amount of duplicated rows, for example 4 rows with UL_ID 17097687 will be marked all as 17097687x004, it doesn't work for numbering those rows as needed, example: 17097687x001, 17097687x002, 17097687x003 and 17097687x004. As mentioned, the solution from P.Salmon works, but I'm grateful for your help non the less.

Comment: Oh, ok, I misread the question, sorry ;) Glad the other answers work for you !